# Tracking time of last modification in Exasol databases

Tags: database, exasolution

In an Exasol database, we want to know for each row when it was last changed.

Other DMBS offer things like hooks/triggers that run arbitrary functions, or even `ON UPDATE` statements. Searching for these terms, I couldn't find anything specific for Exasol.

Combining `last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `last_modified=DEFAULT` [is possible](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/data_types/defaultvalues.htm), but still requires an explicit (if generic) addition to every query.

How can we automatically maintain last-modified timestamps in Exasol?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you can't do it automatically on Exasol, because there are no triggers.

What you can do is to create a processor statement which will recognize an update statement and run a second update to modify the `last_modified` column. Of course the `last_modified` needs to be in every table where you run an update or you will need to toggle this updating script depending on the target table.